# How can I disable whole tabs in broadleaf admin?

Tags: broadleaf-commerce

I would like to disable some of the tabs in the admin module for my extended category entity.

I see that `CategoryImpl` has a static class `Presentation` that contains the metadata which tabs to show, but how do I override those values?

```
public static class Presentation {

    public static class Tab {

        public static class Name {

            public static final String Marketing = "CategoryImpl_Marketing_Tab";
            public static final String Media = "CategoryImpl_Media_Tab";
            public static final String Advanced = "CategoryImpl_Advanced_Tab";
            public static final String Products = "CategoryImpl_Products_Tab";
            public static final String SearchFacets = "CategoryImpl_categoryFacetsTab";
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can override admin annotations for removing tabs, this link will be helpful to you, [Admin Metadata Overrides](http://www.broadleafcommerce.com/docs/core/current/broadleaf-concepts/admin/admin-metadata-overrides).

If you can change the source code, then add `excluded=true` in any @AdminPresentation annotation. This will also remove tabs.